# Sending data to Firebase Cloud Function via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send data through post OR get to **firebase cloud function** but couldn't get it work.

Here is my **ajax**:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'https://us-ceXXX1-reXXXts-fXXa-pr.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            body: {
                mobileNo: "WzkyMzXXXXXXXXXXXc5ODBd"
            },
            success: function(data){
              console.log('succes: '+data);
            }
          });
```

And Here Is Cloud Function:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var responsez = response;

    console.log("DATA IS:"+request.data);    //prints undefined
    console.log("BODY IS:"+JSON.stringify(request.body));  //prints BODY ID: {}
    var mobNo = request.body.mobileNo;
    var options = {
      body: {mobileNo: mobNo, applicationVersion: "1.0"},
      url: 'http://nxxxpi.fixxxa.wxb.pk/GetxxxxxxoUxr',
      headers: {
            'appKey':'jDxxxxxxxOr',
            'appId':'2xxxxx9'
      },
      json: true
    }
    cors(request, response, () => {requestz.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      responsez.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    })});
});
```

And It console logs.

> DATA IS: undefined
>
> BODY IS: {}

**EDIT:**  HERE IS THE FIREBASE CONSOLE:

After adding:

```
console.log("BODY MOBILE:"+JSON.stringify(request.body.mobileNo));
console.log("ONLY MOBILE:"+JSON.stringify(request.mobileNo));
```

[image]

Comment: `method: 'GET', ` shouldn't this be POST as you are passing data in request body

Comment: use `data: {
                mobileNo: "WzkyMzXXXXXXXXXXXc5ODBd"
            }` instead of using `body`

Comment: @Niladri , I have tried both suggestions of your's. Not working :(

Comment: what you get in firebase console?

Comment: the data should be available in `request.body` after post

Comment: @Niladri , Please see edit in question.

Comment: can you post the updated code after the change i suggested ? changing it to 'POST

Comment: @Niladri, I got it to working with your suggestion. there was a typo. Thanks. Please post answer, So that i can accept it.

Comment: ok thanks you are welcome. posted it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few issues in your code

1. change the method to `POST` instead of `GET` in your ajax call as you are passing the data in request body
2. use the `data` property instead of `body` in the ajax call . it should work now. The data will be available in `request.body` inside the firebase function

   ```
   $.ajax({
           url: 'https://us-ceXXX1-reXXXts-fXXa-pr.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld',
           dataType: "json",
           method: 'POST',
           crossDomain: true,
           data: {
               mobileNo: "WzkyMzXXXXXXXXXXXc5ODBd"
           },
           success: function(data){
             console.log('succes: '+data);
           }
         });
   ```